# Streaming a file from HDFS vs copying it to local disk

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, heap-memory

In my Java application I am using a text file(size ~ 300 MB) which is kept in HDFS. Each line of the file contains a string and an Integer ID separated by a comma. I am reading the file line by line and creating Hashmaps(String, ID) from it.

The file looks like this:

```
String1,Integer1
String2,Integer2
...
```

Now, I am currently reading the file from HDFS directly using Apacha Hadoop configuration and FileSystem Object.

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.addResource("core-site.xml"));
conf.addResource("hdfs-site.xml"));
conf.set("fs.hdfs.impl", org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.class.getName());
conf.set("fs.file.impl", org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem.class.getName());

path= "<some location in HDFS>"
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(path), conf);
in = fs.open(new Path(path));
```

The input Stream "in" is passed to another function called **read(InputStream in)** for reading the file.

```
  public void init(InputStream is) throws Exception {
    ConcurrentMap<String, String> pageToId = new ConcurrentHashMap();
    ConcurrentMap<String, String> idToPage = new ConcurrentHashMap();
    logger.info("Free memory: " + Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
    InputStreamReader stream = new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(stream);
    List<String> pageIdMappingColumns = ServerProperties.getInstance().getIdMappingColumns();
    String line;
    int line_no=0;

    while (true) {
        try {
            line = reader.readLine();

            if (line == null) {
                break;
            }
            line_no++;
            //System.out.println("Free memory: " + Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
            String[] values = line.split(COMMA);
            //System.out.println("Free memory: " + Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
            if (values.length < pageIdMappingColumns.size()) {
                throw new RuntimeException(PAGEMAPPER_INVALID_MAPPING_FILE_FORMAT);
            }

            String id = EMPTY_STR;
            String page = EMPTY_STR;
            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                String s = values[i].trim();
                if (PAGEID.equals(pageIdMappingColumns.get(i))) {
                    id = s;
                    continue;
                }
                if (PAGENAME.equals(pageIdMappingColumns.get(i))) {
                    page = s;
                }
            }
            pageToId.put(page, id);
            idToPage.put(id, page);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(PAGEMAPPER_INIT + e.toString() + " on line " + line_no);

        }
    }
    logger.info("Free memory: " + Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
    logger.info("Total number of lines: " + line_no);
    reader.close();
    ConcurrentMap<String, String> oldPageToId = pageToIdRef.get();
    ConcurrentMap<String, String> oldIdToPage = idToPageRef.get();
    idToPage.put(MINUS_1, START);
    idToPage.put(MINUS_2, EXIT);
    pageToId.put(START, MINUS_1);
    pageToId.put(EXIT, MINUS_2);

    /* Update the Atomic reference hashmaps in memory in two conditions
    1. If there was no map in memory(first iteration)
    2. If the number of page-names and page-id pairs in the mappings.txt file are more than the previous iteration
    */

    if (oldPageToId == null || oldIdToPage != null && oldIdToPage.size() <= idToPage.size() && oldPageToId.size() <= pageToId.size()) {
        idToPageRef.set(idToPage);
        pageToIdRef.set(pageToId);
        logger.info(PAGEMAPPER_INIT + " " + PAGEMAPPER_UPDATE_MAPPING);
    } else {
        logger.info(PAGEMAPPER_INIT + " " + PAGEMAPPER_LOG_MSZ);
    }
}
```

I am closing the stream when the work is done like this:

```
IOUtils.closeQuietly(is);
```

I am executing the above code every 1 hour since the file is being changed in HDFS in that duration. So now, I am getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.

My question is: Is it better to copy the file to disk and then use it rather than directly accessing it from HDFS as far as memory requirements are concerned ?

Note: The file has > 3200000 lines.

Answer (score 0):

Stream is always the way to choose.

You're receiving OutOfMemory because you never close your stream, hence memory leak.

Either manually close your stream or use try-with-resource

**Edit**

```
pageToId.put(page, id);
idToPage.put(id, page);
```

You're storing atleast 2x your file size in memory. Which is roughly 600MB.

After that, you assign that value to some `ref` variable:

```
idToPageRef.set(idToPage);
pageToIdRef.set(pageToId);
```

I guess that you're still having reference to old `ref` data somewhere, hence the internal map data is not released.

You also have resource leak at

```
throw new RuntimeException(PAGEMAPPER_INVALID_MAPPING_FILE_FORMAT);
```

You should use try-with-resource or manually close your stream in `finally` block.

Comment: I am closing the stream. Sorry, forgot to add that to my post.

Comment: So what do you do with your `String[] values`. You must have memory leak somewhere, please post relevant code

Comment: I am creating Hashmaps of <String, Int> and <Int, String>

Comment: So your whole file is accumulated to those HashMaps. Pretty obvious it will throw OutOfMemory

Comment: How is that obvious ? As in, where exactly could the leak be - in the split[] function or just populating the maps. As i said, the hashmaps are going to be populated with the updated file every hour, so it is no throwing OutOfMemory the first time, but some time later.

Comment: You're storing atleast 2x your file size in memory: `pageToId.put(page, id); idToPage.put(id, page);`. Which is roughly 600MB. You also have resource leak at `throw new RuntimeException(PAGEMAPPER_INVALID_MAPPING_FILE_FORMAT);`. You should use try-with-resource